# Memoization in Rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memoization, code-duplication

I'm working with Rails 4.0 and I want to eliminate some duplicate lines but I don't know the implications doing this in Rails. As I understand an instance of a controller is created in every request <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597877/rails-how-does-controller-instance-variables-work)</sup>.

```
class ResetController < ApplicationController
  def reset_password
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user
      ...
  end

  def reset_user_token
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user
      ...
  end
end
```

If I'm not using Rails, my idea is extract a private method using memoization and remove the duplicated lines:

```
private

def user
  @user ||= User.find_by_email(params[:email])
end
```

Is it a good idea do this in Rails controller? How do you improve this code? I have a similar problem in a lot of parts of the application.

Related:
 - [When to use memoization in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/696338/462015)
 - [Rails Best Practices: Use memoization](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/59-use-memoization)

Comment: its perfectly fine in this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems not to have much to do with memoization, since as you say yourself, a new instance is started between those requests, so nothing would be 'stored'.

Still removing those duplicates in your code is a good idea. The Rails way to do this in your case would be a before_filter:

```
class ResetController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_user

  protected
  def find_user
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    # here you could add some exception handling and prevent execution of action if no user is found (assuming you want to do this)
  end
```